Using the Clearpath Jackal packages for autonomous navigation ROS Humble
I've been trying to understand how to use the jackal and jackal_simulator repos to implement autonomous navigation (via a behavior tree).
I'm able to launch the gazebo simulation and control the robot manually by publishing on the /cmd_vel topic, however I would like to use the provided jackal_control and jackal_navigation packages to implement autonomous navigation.
What I'm struggling to understand is how to work with the jackal_control and jackal_navigation packages for example to publish a goal pose and have the robot move to it.
Any help/resources would be appreciated!

Start with the Nav2 tutorials on the docs website: https://docs.clearpathrobotics.com/docs/ros/tutorials/navigation_demos/overview The overview page begins with install instructions and then continue through SLAM, localization and Nav2 pages. The earlier ones walk you through getting your map and localization sorted so that you can run the autonomous navigation using Nav2 by the end.

I have tried to follow those tutorials however gazebo fortress crashes, looking at the log files it seems to have something to do with the controller manager not working properly.  [ERROR] [spawner-7]: process[spawner-7] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM' [INFO] [spawner-7]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[spawner-7] [ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 19314, exit code -15, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager-timeout 60 joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args -r __ns:=/j100_0000'].

Please provide the full terminal output, you could update your question or create a different question and link me to it. It probably makes more sense to close this question and open a new one about the particular issue you are having. Those error messages are about sigint and don't tell you what is actually going wrong.  The actual error messages will be earlier in the output.

I managed to solve the issue by moving from WSL to a native Ubuntu environment, now I'm able to run the simulation with no problems!
